# How to return to last view without pop

Tags: ios, objective-c

On didSelectRowAtIndexPath I want to return to the previous viewcontroller. I'm using this code, at the moment:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But, I don't want to pop from navigationcontroller. Because, when the user "clicks" on back button, I want to return to this view.

So, I want to back to previous controller without popping it from navigationcontroller. It is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "return to this view", do you mean the view where you have the code you posted (the controller with the table view)? Do you mean the same instance of the controller (as opposed to a new instance of it)? It would be bad UI design to go back to a previous controller, then use a back button to go back to the one you just came from. You should go forward with a push, and backwards with a pop.

Comment: If you're interested in feedback, perhaps you can describe a bit about why you're doing this, because there's a bit of a cognitive dissonance in "pushing" to a previous VC. If you want to jump around between a set of view controllers, there might be other paradigms that are better suited for the problem. Hard to say without understanding the desired UX.

Comment: Make your question clear plz! If you want to go to `UIViewController` which you've popped, you should save this `UIViewController` and push it when you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; instead

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to push the previous view controller ,you can use the UINavigtionController viewControllers attribute.
So you code may like this
`[self presentViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2]] animated:YES completion:nil];`